# FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb(app id) is not registered as a URL Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have read a variety of similar posts on Stack Overflow, but none of them solved my problem. I am getting this error while testing on a real device not the simulator in xCode (FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, fb(app id) is not registered as a URL Scheme), however I have already changed my FacebookAppID, FacebookDisplayName, and added a URLScheme. Here is my .plist file:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong? I followed FB's step-by-step walkthrough for configuring Facebook for your iOS App and am still getting that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Have you writtern below method in your `AppDelegate.m` file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {

BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

// add app-specific handling code here
return wasHandled;
}
```